# errors when I use MeshLambertMaterial

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I use MeshLambertMaterial but finally I found a problem.When I use my notebook(windows 10) , it is normal.Even when I view the example on Three.js ,this problem occurs. These are the errors:

```
three.dpkg?cacheBuster=zh_CN1460645951295:29438 THREE.WebGLProgram: shader          error:  0 gl.VALIDATE_STATUS false gl.getProgramInfoLog C:\fakepath(250,9-30): error X3004: undeclared identifier 'IncidentLight'

Warning: D3D shader compilation failed with default flags. (vs_3_0)
Retrying with avoid flow control
C:\fakepath(250,9-30): error X3004: undeclared identifier   'webgl_45daf4aa877f103d'

Warning: D3D shader compilation failed with avoid flow control flags. (vs_3_0)
Retrying with prefer flow control
C:\fakepath(250,9-30): error X3004: undeclared identifier 'webgl_45daf4aa877f103d'

Warning: D3D shader compilation failed with prefer flow control flags.   (vs_3_0)
Failed to create D3D shaders.
```

Thanks.

Comment: See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/8161 and try the development branch three.js r.76dev.

Comment: will this bug be posted?thanks @WestLangley

Comment: Did you try the development branch, and did it work for you?

Comment: I can only try this after work. :(

Comment: I have tried three.js r.76dev. It really works!@WestLangley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround to prevent these errors on certain Windows platforms when using `MeshLambertMaterial` has been implemented in the three.js r.76dev branch.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please remember to "accept" answers by clicking on the check mark. Thank you.