# Pointlight won't work with Lambert, OK with Phong

Tags: three.js

(I deleted a previous question because now I know the problem and can give a better title. I guess I'll answer this myself.)

This example is from https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Getting-Started

The problem is that the example doesn't work for me on FF45 or GC50. It shows only the gray background. It does work on IE11.

A workaround is to use MeshPhongMaterial instead of MeshLambertMaterial. Then it works on all 3 browsers.

I'm using three.js R75 and Windows 10.  I'm not sure if this is a problem in other situations.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Getting Started with Three.js</title>    
        <script src="three.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        window.onload = function() {

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( 800, 600 );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            var scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
                35,             // Field of view
                800 / 600,      // Aspect ratio
                0.1,            // Near plane
                10000           // Far plane
            );
            camera.position.set( -15, 10, 10 );
            camera.lookAt( scene.position );

            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 5, 5, 5 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xFF0000 } );
            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( mesh );

            var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xFFFF00 );
            light.position.set( 10, 0, 10 );
            scene.add( light );

            renderer.setClearColor( 0xdddddd, 1);
            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @Davide Necchi  Were you using three.js R75 and Windows 10?

Comment: Is this your issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627389/errors-when-i-use-meshlambertmaterial

Comment: @WestLangley - Yes, I'm pretty sure it is. I searched a lot but never got that hit. I've spent much more time on this than I wanted to. Please email me at dave at dbarc.net.  I'm sorry if this is an inappropriate request.